# this.start() doesn't run threat online server

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

I have the code below. When I run it on a local server (windows 10 & Tomcat  8.0.47 ) it all works fine, also on a second computer (ubuntu & Tomcat 8.5) itn runs wothout problems, As soon as I deploy it on an external server (Digital ocean, Linux 4.4.0-112-generic, Tomcat 8.5.27) it doesn't seem to start the threat. Second time I run the start code it gives a IllegalThreadStateException.
Any suggestions where the problem could be?

My code:

Threat:

```
public class Handler extends Thread {

protected DataExchange de;
protected boolean running;

public SearchRequestHandler(DataExchange de) {
    this.de = de;
    running = false;

}

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                   running = true;
                  //do Stuff



                try {
                    running = false;
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

    }

public void startIfNotStarted() {
        if (!this.isAlive()) {
            this.start();
        } else if (!running)
            synchronized (this) {
                {
                    this.notify();
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Class that calls it:

```
public class controller {

    private static DataExchange de = new DataExchange();
    private static Handler h = new Handler(de);

public static void startThread(Info info) {

    de.addInfo(info);

    h.startIfNotStarted();

}
}
```

My stack trace when I run the program for the second time:

> java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
>     java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
>     Handler.startIfNotStarted(SearchRequestHandler.java:235)
>     controller.startThreat(Search_controller.java:71)
>     controller.Controller.getMail(Controller.java:30)
>     webServlet.SearchServlet.doPost(SearchServlet.java:110)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: A) follow java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase - not **c**ontroller thus! B) why exactly does your controller have **static** fields C) the real problem here is the underlying design: you want to call start() exactly ones, in a controlled setup. The fact that you somehow seem to call start repeatedly (thus you introduced that method) indicates that your underlying design is somehow at fault. You are fixing a symptom, instead of making sure that there is **exactly one** call to start().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
 * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
 * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
 *
 * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
 */
if (threadStatus != 0)
    throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

Your thread might be dead to the time you call `this.start();`. Note that **you can't `start` the same instance of `Thread` more than once.**

> A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Also, there is no need to use the `running` field. You can check the `Thread.State` by `Thread#getState`:

```
if (this.getState() == State.NEW) {
    this.start();
}
```

You'd better not invoke `start` under the conditions. Make a proper call within the controller once. To `start` a thread means to **init** it, rather than to **resume** it:

```
class Controller {

    private static Handler h = new Handler(de);

    static {
        h.start(); // it's guaranteed that the statement is called once
    }

}
```

Comment: Can that happen even after I undeployed and deployed the app from tomcat?

Comment: @TimDJ, no, do you invoke `h.start()` anywhere?

Comment: `startIfNotStarted` is called in the controller, does it mean it can be invoked many times?

Comment: Yes it can. the idea is that eveythime data is added it checks if the threat is already running, if not start it and if it waiting that it will be interupted to continue.

Comment: I tried rebooting the droplet so I knew for certain all old instances would be gone, but the same problem remains.

Comment: @TimDJ, I updated the answer, is it possible to rewrite logic in that way?

Comment: @TimDJ, all you need is scheduling the thread work by `wait-notify`, you don't need restart/start/resume the thread.

Comment: rewrote the logic.  I got no more errors in the threats, also not te expected result, but that looks like a database problem I will try to fix first. thanks a lot or bringing me 1 step further.

Comment: @TimDJ, glad to hear that ;) if you need my help, ping me a message here